# CSS Specificity and what appears to be selective priority

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-specificity

I am using JQuery UI to create a modal window that pops up and prompts you to enter some information into forms.  If a user doesn't enter the required information, then the text field is highlighted in red with a red border.

However, because I manually changed the border of the fields, the border is only changing to red for the textarea.  Even though I have the same CSS rules for my input and textfield, there is a difference in my result.

**Error for Input field:**

[image]

**Error for Textarea:**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
#emailField input, textarea
{
    padding: .7em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error{
    border: 1px solid #fb483d;
    background: #fef1ec url(/Content/themes/css/images/ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #cd0a0a;
}
```

When I look at the CSS through the developer console, I see where one is taking precedence over the other.  But why should there be any difference?

**CSS for Input field:**

[image]

**CSS for Textarea:**

[image]

Simply put, I'd like a red border around both my input fields and my textarea, but I'd also like to understand why there appears to be selective priority.

Comment: `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-error` is more specific than `textarea`, that's why the textarea's border is being overridden by jQuery UI. `#emailField input` on the other hand is more specific because it contains an id selector. the only solution is to make your selector for the textarea more specific. It needs to contain two classes + 1 other thing, or an id.

Comment: Here's a really good article on css specificity. http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma selectors do not obey the distributive property.

`a b, c` matches `a b` and `c`; it is not equivalent to `a c`.

Therefore, your `#emailField input` selector is more specific than `.ui-state-error` (since it includes an ID selector), whereas `textarea` is less specific (since it does not include an ID selector.

Comment: Thanks.  This really came down to my misunderstanding of the comma selector.  I assumed that the `#emailField` id was appended to both the `input` and `textarea`.  I now know otherwise...

Answer (score 2):

It's because you specified the parent for input in your CSS

```
#emailField input, textarea
```

So you'll have to make the `.ui-..` rules more specific

```
body #emailField .ui-..
```

or something similar.

More info on this http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: I'd rather not make the ui rules more specific.  So my goal will be to somehow make my custom rules less specific, but still specific enough that it applies to only certain elements...